# specify rows number in every item in bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, carousel

I'm using bootstrap carousel, where it's devided to items.
The first item should always be with active class and the others only class=item.

I'm requesting data, and getting response  using angularjs, trying to fill the items with ng-repeat

now my problem is the first item should be class=item active, and get only 4 rows.
The other items should be with class=item and every item get only 4 rows.

The request response has more than 70 rows. i'm stuck here, how can I devide the 70 rows to 4 in the first active class, and the rest in the other items (4 rows in each item)

Carousel code :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">


    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/kababji.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Kababji</center></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/alsaniour.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Al Saniour</center></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/pizzahut.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Pizza Hut</center></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/tabliyetmassaad.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Tabiliyet Massaad</center></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/burgerking.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Burger King</center></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/malektaouk.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Malek Taouk</center></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/pizzahut.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Pizza Hut</center></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/restaurants/tabliyetmassaad.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"><Br><center>Tabiliyet Massaad</center></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: do you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11487/  ?

Comment: eum no it's not close

Comment: look at this https://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11489/

Comment: trying it, this is what I want, thank you

Comment: ...welcome..just inform me if you face any problem

Comment: ok. working with that, but the number or returned raws is not fix, it can be changed, how can I handle that using array n index ?

Comment: my mistake.. It's working perfectly, Thank you

Comment: see this updated one https://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11490/ it works according to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to show 4 response array items in one carousel item, you can loop through your response array using ng-repeat and show only those items whose index is completely divisible by 4.For example you have 20 items in an array that you want to loop through.You can put a condition in your `ng-repeat` using `ng-if` to show only 0th,4th,8th,etc.. items i.e. `($index % 4 == 0)` and inside that you can can show 0th,1st,2nd and 3rd items for first row , 4th,5th,6th and 7th for 2nd row ...and so on..

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11490/) demonstrating the same.